# Virtual Functions C++: virtual function already has a body

Tags: c++, virtual

I'm having trouble in implementing a virtual function declared at a abstract class in two other classes, in different header.

When I implement in Class ProtocolLogin the virtual function "parsePacket" that is already implemented at ProtocolGame, the compiler returns "function already has a body".

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "private: virtual void __cdecl ProtocolGame::parsePacket(class NetworkMessage &)" (?parsePacket@ProtocolGame@@EEAAXAEAVNetworkMessage@@@Z) already defined in protocolgame.obj

Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ProtocolLogin::parsePacket(class NetworkMessage &)" (?parsePacket@ProtocolLogin@@UEAAXAEAVNetworkMessage@@@Z)
```

Then I try to create a new virtual function called parseWater, that will be implemented only at Class ProtocolLogin, the compiler returns me "function need to be declared at ProtocolGame", but if I do so, I get again: "function already has a body". So, I just don't follow anymore. Help me understand please :)

Its like an endless circle.

```
    class Protocol (Header File 1)
{
    public:
        explicit Protocol(Connection_ptr connection) : m_connection(connection)
        virtual ~Protocol() = default;

        // non-copyable
        Protocol(const Protocol&) = delete;
        Protocol& operator=(const Protocol&) = delete;

        virtual void parsePacket(NetworkMessage&) {}
        void onRecvMessage(NetworkMessage& msg); // Function that calls parsePacket
        virtual void onRecvFirstMessage(NetworkMessage& msg) = 0; 

class ProtocolGame final : public Protocol (Header File 2)
{
    public:
        // static protocol information
        enum {server_sends_first = true};
        enum {protocol_identifier = 0}; // Not required as we send first
        enum {use_checksum = true};
        static const char* protocol_name() {
            return "gameworld protocol";
        }

        explicit ProtocolGame(Connection_ptr connection);

            private:
        void parsePacket(NetworkMessage& msg) final; //implementation //Works
        void onRecvFirstMessage(NetworkMessage& msg) final; //implementation //Works

     class ProtocolLogin final : public Protocol (Header File 3)
{
    public:
        // static protocol information
        enum {server_sends_first = false};
        enum {protocol_identifier = 0x01};
        enum {use_checksum = true};
        static const char* protocol_name() {
            return "login protocol";
        }

        explicit ProtocolLogin(Connection_ptr connection) : Protocol(connection) {}

        void onRecvFirstMessage(NetworkMessage& msg); //work
        void parsePacket(NetworkMessage& msg); // dont work
```

Comment: Unclear whar is the real code and what is the real error. Please provide the code as is, and put the errors by the lines those errors are reported. On a side note, what is the purpose of sprinkling your code with final? I believe, it is a bad practice.

Comment: For one thing, `void onRecvLiquid();` is not virtual

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And neither is `parseAlcohol()`, so you specifying it as final is incorrect.

Comment: I've edited and changed the functions I've misspelled when I quoted it here. Sorry. Its correct now. Review it guys, please :)

Comment: @SergeyA  I need call parseDrink inside a function of protocol.cpp and I need it to be called inside the two other classes, that are declared in different header files

Comment: Sorry, @Xabirau, it makes no sense. Edit your question the way I suggeted - full code, full errors by the lines those are reported.

Comment: @SergeyA Just edited, hope its the way you suggested. Please, take a look again.

Comment: Not the full code. However, with the errors actually posted, it makes more sense. You do not have one function defined, and another one is defined twice.

Comment: @SergeyA So how can I define parsePacket inside ProtocolLogin, without getting error?

Comment: You have defined it twice. Since you refuse to provide the code, i can help you no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseWater` is the only final function that is declared as `final`.

All other `final` functions have no `virtual` keyword somewhere.

As StoryTeller pointed out *"You don't have to restate the virtual specifier in derived classed."*

Comment: I've edited and changed the functions I've misspelled when I quoted it here. Sorry. Its correct now. Review it, please :)

Comment: Why did you refuse my edit? Your code still isn't compilable and hardly readable...

Comment: New version works for me (MSVC2015) after fixing the obvious bugs (semicolons, brackets, etc.) - See my code edit

Comment: Sorry Simon, I was updating to look like it is on mine, as SergeyA suggested. Could you look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with C++11, <s>but your derived classes that want to implement the virtual functions need to also declare their implementations as `virtual`.   I don't think `final` removes the need to state `virtual`. (Matter of fact,</s> It's an error to declare a non-virtual function as `final`<s>)</s>

IF you notice, your parent class has `parseWater()` defined and `virtual`, but not `parseAlchohol()`, which is why your `ProtocolAlchohol` class doesn't have a problem declaring `void parseAlchohol() final;`, and `ProtocolWater` has issues with `void parseWater() final;`

p.s., I'm not sure you're getting derivation and OOP right if you're explicitly referring to child class concepts (i.e. water & alchohol) in your parent class, and naming functions based on water & alchohol.

edit:  Never mind my first paragraph.  I guess I always do it as a convention and didn't realize it wasn't necessary.

Comment: You don't *have* to restate the virtual specifier in derived classed.

Comment: "your derived classes that want to implement the virtual functions need to also declare their implementations as virtual." Incorrect.

Comment: The final specifier _"Specifies that a virtual function cannot be overridden in a derived class or that a class cannot be inherited from."_. This might be of use to declare public functions in the base class but protecting them from being overidden in the derived classes. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: I've edited and changed the functions I've misspelled when I quoted it here. Sorry. Its correct now. Review it, please :)

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about using `virtual` in derived classess, I want to make a statement. Unfortunately, in my view C++ is inconsistent in this regard. You may or may not 'restate' virtual. What is even worse, you can make a function virtual when it was not virtual in the base class - which may give a code reader an indication of function being virtual - a wrong indication.

It would be much easier on code maintainers if C++ actually enforced the usage of virtual - requiring it in all redefinitions of virtual functions and forbidding it on redefinitions on non-virtuals.

Comment: I've edited and changed the functions I've misspelled when I quoted it here. Sorry. Its correct now. Review it, please :)

Comment: Those are all none-issues for language fluent programmers.

Comment: @StoryTeller, oh really? Non-issues? ` struct X { }; struct foo : Base<X> { void f(); };`  Is f() virtual?

Comment: @SergeyA, Without a point of invocation and the definition of `Base<>` it's impossible to answer. But not being acquainted with the classes one uses and the language mechanisms involved is not a problem with the language. Your example is irrelevant.

Comment: @StoryTeller, you didn't get the point, I see. Base<> has multiuple specializations. Does the one for struct X have f() virtual? No IDE I know of can point to the  specific specialization of a template class. And just a hint of advice. For someone claiming to be 'fresh out of the university' you are a little bit too bold. You would benefit from trying to understand what someone with 20+ years of professional C++ experience has to say ;)

Comment: @SergeyA, Over 20 years of experience and you haven't learned that ad-hominem arguments are useless!? You still haven't disprovem **my** point. Since in your "problem" specification you provided `X`, there will be no specialization unless you yourself provide it. And in the case it's part of a framework, than just RTFM.

Comment: @StoryTeller, just wait until you get real job and will be given a modest codebase of, say, 10 000 files. Now you are looking into the class definiton and you need to know if you can inherit from it and use it polymorphically or not. By the time you will finish reading TFM, you'd be fired for non-performance. Good luck.